# How to sort XML elements in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML:

```
<project>
  <settings>
     <setting1 name="s1">foo</setting1>
     <setting2 name="s2">bar</setting2>
  </settings>
  <items>
     <item name="a">
        <property1>foo1</property1>
        <property2>bar2</property2>
     </item>
     <item name="c">
        <property1>foo3</property1>
        <property2>bar4</property2>
     </item>
     <item name="b">
        <property1>foo5</property1>
        <property2>bar6</property2>
     </item>
  </items>
</project>
```

I need to sort the xml by attribute "name" of element "item".

I'm doing something like this:

```
[xml]$myXml = Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 $xmlPath

$myXml | Sort-Object {$_.project.items.item.name}

$myXml.Save($xmlPathSorted)
```

Is it possible to do it that easy in PS?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
# Get the items collection
$items = $myXml.project.items
# Sort the items and store in $orderedItems
$orderedItems = $items.item | Sort name
# Removed existing items from xml variable
$items.RemoveAll()
# Append sorted items
$orderedItems | foreach { $items.AppendChild($_) }
```

After running the above test with

```
$myxml.InnerXml
```

And you should see that the `item` elements have been sorted.

Comment: $orderedItems = $items.item | Sort name; returns nothing. Sort is an alias of Sort-Object.