# Powershell script to move properties from middle to end of file

Tags: powershell

I have a configuration file that looks like this:

```
<Configuration>
<Property> 1 />
<Property> 2 />
<ConfigurationRef 1 />
<Property 3 />
</Configuration>
```

What i need is to have always the `<ConfigurationRef 1 />` at the end of file but before `</Configuration>` ends.
What I achieved for now is to move `<ConfigurationRef 1 />` and `</Configuration>` to txt and then append to file:

```
Get-Content C:\file.xconf | Select-String -Pattern '<ConfigurationRef 1 />' | Out-File "C:\outfile.txt"
Get-Content C:\file.xconf | Select-String -Pattern '</Configuration>' | Out-File "C:\outfile.txt" -Append
```

Then:

```
Get-Content C:\outfile.txt | Out-file C:\file.xconf -Append
```

There is a way to do that without exporting it to new txt file ? Because after importing it doesn't look good in file

Comment: Looks like an XML file. [Manipulate it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47343911/503046) as structured document, not as a text.

Comment: @vonPryz Looks like, but isn't valid XML - literal `1`/`2`/`3`'s in the middle of the node definitions aren't valid

Comment: It's a XML file. 1/2/3 I have putted for example.

Comment: Is it always exactly `'<ConfigurationRef 1 />'` and `'</Configuration>'`?

Comment: @DougMaurer Yes. It always be same file to move to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going an other route and simply building a new string array by going through all lines in the original file:

```bsh
$NewContent = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

foreach ($Line in $Content) {
    switch ($Line) {
        "<ConfigurationRef 1 />" {}
        "</Configuration>" {
            # Reached end of Configuration block, adding hardcoded
            # values
            $NewContent.Add("<ConfigurationRef 1 />")
            $NewContent.Add("</Configuration>")
        }
        default { $NewContent.Add($Line) }
    }
}
```

In this case, you will add all lines to the new `[string[]]` array with two exceptions:

- `<ConfigurationRef 1 />` will be ignored
- `</Configuration>` will add the two lines in correct order