# Trying to combine replace and new-item in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a task to make changes to some Config files in a Directory, and the files that need changing are 7, all starting with "Monitoring_Tran_xx".

Within these files there are certain values `(TransactionID="01" AgreedResponseTime="500" SearchProfileID="216")` that need changing but not present across all 7, and will need to check if they are present before replace or creating them.
Also I am trying to insert a new parameter(using new-item) if a certain parameter is equal to a certain value e.g. `if TemplateType = "4152"` then create a new parameter next to it `"DirectoryPoolID = '3' "`

I will appreciate your help on this please.

Thanks

Example of Config file below:

```
<?xml *version="1.0"* ?>
<Monitor>
    <Configuration OperatingMode="Transaction" LogFileName="C:\Program Files\*******s\MonitoringOMTR\MonitorLog_01.log" WriteFileInterval="120" ConnectionKey="**********" />
    <TransactionMonitoringConfig TransactionID="01" AgreedResponseTime="500" SearchProfileID="216" />
    <ShowMessages>
        <Message Name="MOISearchStart" />
        <Message Name="MOOSearchFound" />
        <Message Name="MOOSearchEnd" />
        <Message Name="MOOAlert" />
    </ShowMessages>
    <PerformanceCounters TransactionCount="191" TransactionBreaches="0" />
</Monitor>
```

---

Powershell script that i tried but it didn't quite result well:

```
(Get-Content -Path '***FS2072\UserData$\aroyet01\Desktop\HostPS.txt') |
    if ([bool]((Get-Content -Path "***FS2072\UserData$\aroyet01\Desktop\HostPS.txt") -like '*DirectoryPool*', '*SearchProfile*')) { 
write-host "Found it"
}
else {
 write-host "Did not find it"
}
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'TransactionCount="191"', 'TransactionCount="196"'} |
        Set-Content -Path '***FS2072\UserData$\aroyet01\Desktop\HostPS.txt'
Get-Content -Path '***FS2072\UserData$\aroyet01\Desktop\HostPS.txt'
```

Comment: Config File below
<Monitor>
    <Configuration OperatingMode="Transaction" LogFileName="C:\Program Files\*******s\MonitoringOMTR\MonitorLog_01.log" WriteFileInterval="120" ConnectionKey="**********" />
    <TransactionMonitoringConfig TransactionID="01" AgreedResponseTime="500" SearchProfileID="216" />
    <ShowMessages>
        <Message Name="MOISearchStart" />
        <Message Name="MOOSearchFound" />
        <Message Name="MOOSearchEnd" />
        <Message Name="MOOAlert" />
    </ShowMessages>
    <PerformanceCounters TransactionCount="191" TransactionBreaches="0" />
</Monitor>

Comment: Please update your question with your config file (using code format - 4 space indent like you did with your script) rather than pasting it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a task to make changes to some Config files in a Directory, and the files that need changing are 7, all starting with "Monitoring_Tran_xx".

Stop treating your XML files as raw text - they can be parsed and treated with much better precision :)

First up, we need to parse the document(s) as XML, the easiest way probably being:

```bsh
$xmlDocument = [xml](Get-Content C:\Path\To\)
```

Since you have multiple documents with a common naming pattern, we might use `Get-ChildItem` to discover the files on disk and loop over them to get the paths:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\path\to\config\files\Monitoring_Tran_*.ps1 |ForEach-Object {
  # read each document from disk with `Get-Content`, convert to [xml]
  $xmlDocument = [xml]($_ |Get-Content)
}
```

Next, we need to be able to *navigate* our XML document. PowerShell has native syntax bindings for this:

```bsh
$tmConfig = $xmlDocument.Monitor.TransactionMonitoringConfig
```

or, you can use `XPath` expressions to navigate the document as well:

```bsh
$tmConfig = $xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/Monitor/TransactionMonitoringConfig")
```

> Within these files there are certain values (`TransactionID="01" AgreedResponseTime="500" SearchProfileID="216"`) that need changing but not present across all 7, and will need to check if they are present before replace or creating them

To check whether a named attribute *exists* on a node we can use [the `HasAttribute()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement.hasattribute):

```bsh
if($tmConfig.HasAttribute('TransactionID')){
  # attribute exists, let's update it!
  $tmConfig.SetAttribute('TransactionID', 123) # replace 123 with whatever ID you need
}
```

> Also I am trying to insert a new parameter(using new-item) if a certain parameter is equal to a certain value e.g. if `TemplateType = "4152"` then create a new parameter next to it `"DirectoryPoolID = '3' "`

In the case where you want to add a new attribute to a node only if another attribute has a specific value, you can use `GetAttribute()` and `SetAttribute()`:

```bsh
if($xmlNode.GetAttribute('TemplateType') -eq "4152"){
  $xmlNode.SetAttribute("DirectoryPoolID", 3)
}
```

Whenever you're done, save the document back to file:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\path\to\config\files\Monitoring_Tran_*.ps1 |ForEach-Object {
  # read each document from disk with `Get-Content`, convert to [xml]
  $xmlDocument = [xml]($_ |Get-Content)

  <# write all the code to inspect and update the attributes here #>

  # write document back to disk
  $xmlDocument.Save($_.FullName)
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, Thanks for your comment and help.

Comment: I tried using the last bit - I inserted the if statements in the middle as mentioned, but came back with the below error:

Comment: Exception calling "SelectSingleNode" with "1" argument(s): "'\\BBCFS2072\UserData$\aroyet01\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\OMTR\Monitor_Tran*' has an invalid token."
At line:7 char:3
+   $tmConfig = $xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("\\BBCFS2072\UserData$\ar ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
 You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:18 char:4
+ if($xmlNode.GetAttribute('TemplateType') -eq "4158"){

Comment: @TimmyAroyewun pass your file system paths to `Get-ChildItem` in place of `C:\path\to\config\files\Monitoring_Tran_*.ps1`. Don't change the expression in `SelectSingleNode()`

Comment: Hi Mathias, this is what I am getting, as I moved the Directory to another Drive: 
Exception calling "SelectSingleNode" with "1" argument(s): "'D:\Timmy\OMTR\Monitor_Transaction_*' has an invalid qualified name."
At line:7 char:3
+   $tmConfig = $xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("D:\Timmy\OMTR\Monitor_Tr ...
+

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:14 char:6
+   if($xmlNode.GetAttribute('TemplateType') -eq "4152"){

Comment: @TimmyAroyewun Please take the time to read (and maybe test the examples, in the console) the answer instead of just blindly copy-pasting - `$xmlNode` is just an _example name_, since your question never stated which node would have `TemplateType` as an attribute, and there's no example of it in the sample XML.

Comment: I did read your answer thoroughly, each config file content in the directory are not consistent, hence why we need to run checks to ascertain which one has the 'TemplateType'. I am not fully conversant with PS, which is why I am trying to learn more. I am sorry if my comments are not helpful or useful to you. I have a deadline tomorrow morning. I guess I will try and figure it out on my own. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Morning - I have had progress and thanks for correcting my mistakes, I had this though: Method invocation failed because [System.Xml.XmlElement] does not contain a method named 'AddAttribute'.
At line:18 char:3
+   $xmlNode.AddAttribute("DirectoryPoolID", 3)
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (AddAttribute:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: @TimmyAroyewun just realized that should have been `SetAttribute()`, not `AddAttribute()`. `$xmlNode.SetAttribute("DirectoryPoolID", 3)` should work

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code snippet i can only assist by giving you the advice to start with basic Powershell syntax documentation.

```
help about_If
help about_Pipelines
```

To give you an idea... Your `if` is placed in a pipeline. Your `ForEach-Object` is not placed in a pipeline. Both of these don't work the way you posted it. You can start from something like this:

```
$Content = '***FS2072\UserData$\aroyet01\Desktop\HostPS.txt'
if ($Content -condition 'Yourcondition') {
    $Content | ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace 'Regex', 'Replacement'
    }
} else {
    'Your else here'
}
```

For editing the xml file you can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47343234/how-to-sort-xml-elements-in-powershell/47343911#47343911) as hinted by vonPryz in [this question today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63464882/powershell-script-to-move-properties-from-middle-to-end-of-file/63465134#63465134).

Comment: Thanks @philmph for your help and comment. The task is abit tedious and requires inspecting and adding new items if the contents don't already exist.