# Similar XML Config Files in a Directory needs updating - Adding new attributes and replacing existing attributes within SingleNode

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a task to make changes to some Config files in a Directory, and the files that need changing are 7, all starting with "Monitoring_Tran_xx".
Within these files there are certain values (TransactionID="01" AgreedResponseTime="500" SearchProfileID="216") that need changing but not present across all 7, and will need to check if they are present before replace or creating them. Also I am trying to insert a new parameter(using new-item) if a certain parameter is equal to a certain value e.g. if TemplateType = "4152" then create a new parameter next to it "DirectoryPoolID = '3' "

I will appreciate your help on this please.

Thanks

Example of Config file below:

```
<?xml *version="1.0"* ?>
<Monitor>
    <Configuration OperatingMode="Transaction" LogFileName="C:\Program Files\*******s\MonitoringOMTR\MonitorLog_01.log" WriteFileInterval="120" ConnectionKey="**********" />
    <TransactionMonitoringConfig TransactionID="01" AgreedResponseTime="500" SearchProfileID="216" TemplateType="4152" />
    <ShowMessages>
        <Message Name="MOISearchStart" />
        <Message Name="MOOSearchFound" />
        <Message Name="MOOSearchEnd" />
        <Message Name="MOOAlert" />
    </ShowMessages>
    <PerformanceCounters TransactionCount="191" TransactionBreaches="0" />
</Monitor>
```

Powershell script that i tried but it didn't quite result well:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Timmy\OMTR\Monitor_Transaction_* |ForEach-Object {
  # read each document from disk with `Get-Content`, convert to [xml]
  $xmlDocument = [xml]($_ |Get-Content)

  <# write all the code to inspect and update the attributes here #>

  $tmConfig = $xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/Monitor/TransactionMonitoringConfig")
  
 

  if($tmConfig.HasAttribute('TransactionID')){
  # attribute exists, let's update it!
  $tmConfig.SetAttribute('TransactionID', 650) # replace 123 with whatever ID you need

  $xmlNode = $xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/Monitor/TransactionMonitoringConfig")

  if($xmlNode.GetAttribute('TemplateType') -eq "4152")
{
  $xmlNode.AddAttribute([System.xml.xmlNode] "DirectoryPoolID = '3'")
}

}
 # write document back to disk
  $xmlDocument.Save($_.FullName)
}
```

Comment: Please qualify "didn't quite result well" - include any errors you're seeing (in full) in [your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63508649/edit) (not in a comment)

Comment: Cannot find an overload for "SetAttribute" and the argument count: "1".
At line:19 char:3
+   $xmlNode.SetAttribute("DirectoryPoolID = '3'")
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: It's `SetAttribute("DirectoryPoolId", "3")`, please see [my comment on the duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63470287/trying-to-combine-replace-and-new-item-in-powershell#comment112303358_63471796)